# calling setAdapter in onPostExecute returns NullException

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Hi I have the following code which always causes a null pointer exception:

```
protected void onPostExecute(List<String> result) {     
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getApplicationContext(),R.id.spinner1);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    Iterator<String> it = result.iterator();

    while(it.hasNext()){
        String v = (String) it.next();
        adapter.add(v);
    }

    Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spin.setAdapter(adapter); //this line
}
```

If I comment the `this line` line, the exception is not thrown, and I have checked already and spin is not null neither is adapter.

Why am I still getting the following error?

```
12-13 05:08:55.446: E/AndroidRuntime(1349): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070002 type #0x12 is not valid
12-13 05:08:55.446: E/AndroidRuntime(1349): at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2110)
```

Comment: I believe it is due to the resource id of the spinner as the error recommends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a *layout* resource to the ArrayAdapter constructor, like:

```
new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getApplicationContext(), 
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```